# Follow up to multiple result tabs in Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image: Workbench action output displaying *only* individual result]

@Mike Lischke -- this is in response to your reply to my question here regarding multiple result tabs ([Multiple Result Tabs in Workbench](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/253228/multiple-result-tabs-in-workbench))

This is a screenshot of the tutorial I am viewing to teach myself SQL. As you can see, the action output shows all the SELECT statements with different time stamps. I am pretty sure the instructor is NOT highlighting/selecting the code in the editor before running `command/shift + enter`. Rather, only the last SELECT statement terminating with a semi-colon is being run. All previous SELECT statements are being ignored. He has all the SELECT statements in the same query editor window like I do. I am wondering if there is possibly a setting that I am missing. Again, I may be mistaken but I really think this was how it was working for me at first. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: So can we close this question? Since you have detail clarification in the [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/253228/multiple-result-tabs-in-workbench) which was answered to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see here is not the result sets but the Action Output. This shows all the queries that were run in the current Workbench session, with error or success messages and timing. Right click in the grid for a context menu which allows you to clear that output:

[image]